# Why can't I iterate through pandas sum?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group by the key 'ASIN' and sum the columns of the groups, and then I want to iterate through and print each column ('Name','ASIN','Items Shipped').

```
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    gk = df[['Name','ASIN','Items Shipped']].groupby('ASIN')
    print(gk.sum())
    for row in gk.sum():
        print(row)
```

Printing gk.sum() shows part of the Dataframe, I can't see much but I can see that it has a bunch of 'ASIN' listings. But if I try to iterate through those rows so I can print the individual 'Name', 'ASIN', and 'Items Shipped' rows, I only get one printed string of 'Items Shipped'. I'm pulling my hair out! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set `as_index=False` in your `groupby` as - `groupby("ASIN", as_index=False)` and see if you can print them all when you iterate.

Comment: can you please share sample dataframe and sample output. You can always do a groupby and sum to get the values into another dataframe. I don't see the challenge. And what do you want to sum please? `'Items Shipped'` or some other column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to loop over dataframe `gk.sum()`, you can loop over dataframe rows by using `pd.DataFrame.iterrows()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

gk = df[['Name','ASIN','Items Shipped']].groupby('ASIN')
print(gk.sum())

for index, row in gk.sum().iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
columnname1    value1
columnname2    value2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
columnname1    value1
columnname2    value2
Name: 2, dtype: int64
...
```